# Many to many relationship between two tables in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've two tables tbl_user and tbl_favItems looks like below:

```
 +-----+----------+          +-----+----------+
 |  ID |   Name   |          | ID  |   Name   |
 +-----+----------+          +-----+----------+ 
 |  1  |  Johan   |          |  1  |  Movies  |
 |  2  |  Peter   |          |  2  |  Food    |
 |  3  |  Kevin   |          |  3  |  Mobiles |
 |  4  |  Harry   |          |  4  |  Sports  |
 +-----+----------+          +-----+----------+
     User Table                 Fav. Table
```

Here i need to some logic like: Suppose `Johan` can have fav. `Movies, Mobiles`, and `Peter` can have fav. `Food, Mobiles, Sports`.etc;. In this case how can i relate `fav.ID 1,3` to `Johan` and `fav.ID 2,3,4` to `Peter` in a table? Is it possible?

I need some clue to move forward. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble!

Comment: A relationa table (user_fav) is what you need, with an id_user and id_fav, where a user can store more than 1 fav.

Comment: create a third table with user_id and fav_id. Each user will have as many rows as favorites. The two tables you have now are dictionaries for the third new one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a [many to many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relationship between your tables, To relate your tables introduce a junction table which will hold references for these 2 tables like

user_favourites

user_id (pk of table 1)

item_id (pk of table 2)

Data in this table will look like

```
user_id item_id
1        1
1        3
2        2
2        3
2        4
```

[Associative entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)